# How do I run Mysql queries from the bash shell?

Tags: mysql, bash

Sorry if the question is badly worded, essentially i'm trying to do something like this

```
mysql --user user --p password database -e "    SELECT *  FROM 
`wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE '_sku' AND `meta_value` = '';" | awk ' { print $2 } ' > post_id_data.txt
```

However when I run this style of code i'm getting errors and i'm not sure why, reason being as the mysql statement is straight from phpmyadmin and works when i connect to the mariadb database.
I have tried to remove some of the back ticks so that they are more like this
'' instead of whats being shown but still no luck instead I get this error

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check 
>       the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right 
>       syntax to use near ''wp_postmeta' WHERE 'meta_key' LIKE '_sku' AND 
>       'meta_value' = ''' at line 1

*Another example of code that I have tried can be seen below.*

```
#!/bin/bash
MYSQLUSER="user"
MYSQLPASS="password"
database="wordpress"




#mysql options to be parsed 
MYSQLOPTS="--user=${MYSQLUSER} --password=${MYSQLPASS} ${database}"

mysql ${MYSQLOPTS} << EOFMYSQL
SELECT *  FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE '_sku' AND `meta_value` = '';
EOFMYSQL
```

*I Have also tried*

```
root@3e0a62b6b42c:/# mysql --user=user--password=passowrd wordpress -e 
"SELECT *  FROM 'wp_postmeta' WHERE 'meta_key' LIKE '_sku' AND 
'meta_value' = '';"
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''wp_postmeta' WHERE 'meta_key' LIKE '_sku' AND 'meta_value' = ''' at line 1

Please note that i'm new to Mysql so any references to good learning material where I can do thing such as this is deeply appreciated

Comment: Looks like you're using the wrong quotes. Make sure you're using ' and not `

Comment: That's exactly what I thought but still seem to be getting the same error for whatever reason ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''wp_postmeta' WHERE 'meta_key' LIKE '_sku' AND 'meta_value' = ''' at line 1

Comment: Backticks are the right quotes to escape table and column names but you can't just use another line for the query. Put it in a single line

Comment: Im not sure I understand what your trying to say  do you mean `mysql ${MYSQLOPTS} << EOFMYSQL
SELECT *  FROM 'wp_postmeta' WHERE 'meta_key' LIKE '_sku' AND 'meta_value' = '';
EOFMYSQL` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the semicolon and quotes around column/table names.

The `mysql` tool explodes when you terminate your query with a semicolon.
Use backticks to quote entity names *if you need to*, not quotes.

Try this:

```
"SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE '_sku' AND meta_value = ''"
```

Comment: Tried on `mysql ${MYSQLOPTS} << EOFMYSQL
SELECT *  FROM 'wp_postmeta' WHERE 'meta_key' LIKE '_sku' AND 'meta_value' = ''"
EOFMYSQL` and `mysql --user=user --password=password wordpress -e "SELECT *  FROM 'wp_postmeta' WHERE 'meta_key' LIKE '_sku' AND 'meta_value' = ''"` and get 
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''wp_postmeta' WHERE 'meta_key' LIKE '_sku' AND 'meta_value' = ''' at line 1

Comment: The query works through `mysql --user=user --password=password wordpress -e "SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE '_sku' AND meta_value = ''"`  which is awesome. Thank you